How to get deployed models list in Vertex AI?

In the Vertex AI model registry , we can see the models we've imported . There , we can also see the deployment status of those models .
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectId/locations/us-central1/models
I got this endpoint from the vertex ai api reference , this returns the list of models in the model registry . But in this list , the deployment status of the models is not available .
How to get deployment status of these models? What api do I need to call ? Am I missing any parameters in the endpoint I'm using?
I am using NodeJS .
I am trying to get Vertex AI model registry's model list in my app along with their deployment status.
I expected a json response with deploymentStatus field, but not getting it. Except deploymentStatus I get every field .
